# How to run "mysqldump" and "tar" commands if "exec,passthru,shell_exec,system" are disabled?

Tags: php

In my provider, those functions are disabled:

```
exec,passthru,shell_exec,system
```

thus in my backupping script, I cant execute `mysqldump` and `tar` command. Then what can I do?

Comment: Ask your admin / hoster about alternatives or use phpmyadmin to dump your db

Comment: Use a cron job?

Answer (score 2):

For the database part : As an alternative, you may use `SELECT * INTO OUTFILE`

For details, refer to [Mariadb offical documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/select-into-outfile/) and [Mysql official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html)

So a typical syntax can be (if you want to specify the format)

```
SELECT customer_id, firstname, surname from customer
  INTO OUTFILE '/exportdata/customers.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

So the sample code (say using mysqli) is (amend to suit your needs):

```
<?php
// Connect to the database
$conn = mysqli_connect('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');


// Export the database
$sql = "SELECT * from table_name INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/backup.sql'";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo "Database backup successfully created!";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

// Close the connection
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Note: if you want to "restore" your data, use `LOAD DATA INFILE ...` . See [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 1):

**cronjob**

This assumes the backup is run by the root user, but the process is very similar if it is at the account level.

***/etc/cron.d/backup***

*If you have root access (which is probably unlikely)*

```
MAILTO=root
33 3 * * * root ./backup.sh
```

***crontab -e***

*If you don't have root access*

```
33 3 * * * ./backup.sh
```

**/root/backup.sh**

Rotating 7-day backup

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $HOME
DOW=`date '+%a'`
mysqldump db -udbuser | gzip > db-"$DOW".sql.gz
```

**/root/.my.cnf**

*There are more secure solutions, but if the user has access to your root account and directory, it's too late anyway*

```
[client]
user=dbuser
password=dbpassword
```